# A first chance exception of type 'System.Resources.MissingManifestResourceException' occurred in mscorlib.dll[C++/CLI]

Tags: c++-cli

Application throws exception after code migration from VS2005 to VS2012

Here is the error:

A first chance exception of type 'System.Resources.MissingManifestResourceException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

IDE: VS2012
OS:  Win7
I use C++/CLI form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the solution.

when I Migrated from VS2005 to VS2012 "Resource Logical name" was affected.
In my case, it worked after doing change as shown below:

Step 1: In Solution Explorer, Right-click on Form.resx

Step 2: Managed Resource->General->Resource Logical Name

Step 3: added " $(RootNamespace).%(Filename).resources" in "Logical resource name"